# Android Webview - Apple Music iframe doesn't load

Tags: android, html, iframe, android-webview, apple-music

I have a feed which give me an `iframe` related to Apple Music. It also has `iframe` related to Spotify and others. All other `iframe`s load without issue, but the apple music doesn't.

This is the `iframe` i have for the apple music.

```
<iframe allow="autoplay *; encrypted-media *;" frameborder="0" height="450" style="width:100%;max-width:660px;overflow:hidden;background:transparent;" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-storage-access-by-user-activation allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation" src="https://embed.music.apple.com/us/album/outer-peace/1438769910?app=music&at=1010lpzb"></iframe>
```

I am constructing the html document and then loading it in the WebView using `mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL()`. The same iframe loads fine on webpage or sites like w3schools without issue.

What am i missing here? Happy to provide any details needed.

Comment: Are you allowing 3rd party cookies to be set? 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager#setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(android.webkit.WebView,%20boolean) Maybe access is being denied since the source is attempting to create a cookie.

Comment: I was missing setDomStorageEnabled() for my WebView. Once set, it loads without issue. May be i should have posted the code as well. Thanks all for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i guess it worked out.

you should add `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in  tag of Manifest.

if this can't solves your issue then
Refer to this [Link](https://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2017/04/07/how-i-almost-put-an-iframe-into-a-webview) might be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This probably has to do with the restrictions that Apple puts on privacy, I would suggest that you contact Apple.

Perhaps it has to do with the song, maybe it was taken down?